# Can you handle Exceptions in an autolaunched Flow?

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I am receiving the following Row Lock Error in Flow:

```
Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record
```

When this particular error comes up in Flows, how can I handle this exception? Do flows have the ability to handle error codes?

If this particular error comes up, I would want the system to go through a "pause" element and try again in a future context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a fault connector and `{!$Flow.FaultMessage}` variable to handle this.
[image: Example]
[image]

In the example above, the flow is redirected to the 'Next Steps' assignment if the 'Create Records' operation is successful. If it's not, it follows the fault path. A decision can be added in the fault path to check for specific errors and redirect the flow accordingly.

Comment: How do you know the fault message will say "Record Lock"? Is there a list of these faults online? Asking, because I cannot find a list anywhere.

Comment: Fault message will be the same as the one you mentioned at the top - "This error occurred when the flow...". You can use something like `{!$Flow.FaultMessage}` 'Contains' `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` in the decision (instead of 'Equals') to uniquely identify error messages.